# Check for white space Regex C#

Tags: c#, asp.net, regex

I created a Regex to match the following rule :

> Must contains only upper case and numbers. Must not contains any other charaters including spacing characters (\n, \t, \v, \r, ...).

So I created the following rule :

```
Regex rule = new Regex(@"^[A-Z0-9\S]+");
```

- `^` : Begin of a line / starts with
- `[A-Z0-9]` : contains a character in upper cases, or numbers
- `[\S]` : Doesn't contains a spacing character
- `+` : May contains one or more occurence of the pattern

*I put a `@` character to be able to use escape character `\S`.*

To verify it, I created a simple WebForm, with a `asp:TextBox`, and a valid `asp:Button` to check if it is correct :

**myFile.aspx**

```
<asp:TextBox runat="server" ID="textBox_1"></asp:TextBox>
<asp:Button runat="server" ID="button_1" Text="Check" OnClick="button_1_Click"/>
```

Then I binded the click to check if the rule is verifyied :

**myFile.aspx.cs**

```
protected void button_1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{

    string textbox = textBox_1.Text;
    Regex rule = new Regex(@"^[A-Z0-9\S]+");            

    if (rule.IsMatch(textbox))
    {
        /* Match */
    }
    else
    {
        /* Doesn't match */
    }            
}
```

**My problem :**

When I enter the string `AA AA`, the rule is checked, which is not what I want. Did I wrote wrong my rule ?

**To check the rule**

- `AA AA` is not valid because it contains a spacing character
- `aaaa` is not valid because it doesn't contains at least uppercase or number
- `HELLOWORLD` is valid because it contains only uppercase
- `HELLO654` is valid because it contains only uppercase or numbers

Comment: Added precision on how to valid the rule.

Comment: Little side note, instead of a regex you can use some LINQ: `.All(c => char.IsUpper(c) || char.IsDigit(c))`. Reads much better than a regex.

Comment: No need the `\S` use `^[A-Z0-9]+$`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You probably want to anchor the regex at the end as well. Also you don't need the `\S` portion because `[A-Z0-9]` can't include any space characters anyway.

```
^[A-Z0-9]+$
```

Your current regex doesn't force the match to occur at the end of a string, and so `AAA AAA` passes. Specifically, the first `AAA` passes and the rest of the string isn't required to meet your requirements.

Comment: Thank you @dugas, this precision also removed a bug in which lower case was considered in the rule.

Comment: What does first sign means here??

Comment: I precised explaination on my question below my regex, `^` means **starts with**.

Comment: @Zeratops did'nt noticed that...:P